# Pandas covid dataframe: get cases per day per county

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I am reading covid-19 data from https://ti.saude.rs.gov.br/covid19/download , and I would like to:

- select only rows where 'MUNICIPIO' column has value of 'SÃO LOURENÇO DO SUL';
- then sort by column 'DATA_CONFIRMACAO';
- then count rows in each group, getting a timeseries where "each point is the number of cases per day";
- then plot with x-axis being date, and y-axis being count;

I tried this, without success:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Index(['COD_IBGE', 'MUNICIPIO', 'COD_REGIAO_COVID', 'REGIAO_COVID', 'SEXO',
#        'FAIXAETARIA', 'CRITERIO', 'DA       'FAIXAETARIA', 'CRITERIO', 'DATA_CONFIRMACAO', 'DATA_SINTOMAS',
#        'DATA_EVOLUCAO', 'EVOLUCAO', 'HOSPITALIZADO', 'FEBRE', 'TOSSE',
#        'GARGANTA', 'DISPNEIA', 'OUTROS', 'CONDICOES', 'GESTANTE',
#        'DATA_INCLUSAO_OBITO', 'DATA_EVOLUCAO_ESTIMADA', 'RACA_COR',
#        'ETNIA_INDIGENA', 'PROFISSIONAL_SAUDE', 'BAIRRO', 'HOSPITALIZACAO_SRAG',
#        'FONTE_INFORMACAO', 'PAIS_NASCIMENTO', 'PES_PRIV_LIBERDADE'],

url = "https://ti.saude.rs.gov.br/covid19/download"
data = pd.read_csv('covid-rs.csv', delimiter=';')
result = data[data['MUNICIPIO'] == 'SÃO LOURENÇO DO SUL'].groupby('DATA_CONFIRMACAO').count()
print(result)
```

Output is:

```
                COD_IBGE  MUNICIPIO  COD_REGIAO_COVID  REGIAO_COVID  SEXO  FAIXAETARIA  CRITERIO  ...  ETNIA_INDIGENA  PROFISSIONAL_SAUDE  BAIRRO  HOSPITALIZACAO_SRAG  FONTE_INFORMACAO  PAIS_NASCIMENTO  PES_PRIV_LIBERDADE
DATA_CONFIRMACAO                                                                                    ...
01/07/2020               2          2                 2             2     2            2         2  ...               2                   2       2                    2                 2                2                   2
01/09/2020               2          2                 2             2     2            2         2  ...               2                   2       2                    2                 2                2                   2
01/12/2020              24         24                24            24    24           24        24  ...              24                  24      24                   24                24               24                  24
02/07/2020               3          3                 3             3     3            3         3  ...               3                   3       3                    3                 3                3                   3
02/09/2020               5          5                 5             5     5            5         5  ...               5                   5       5                    5                 5                5                   5
...                    ...        ...               ...           ...   ...          ...       ...  ...             ...                 ...     ...                  ...               ...              ...                 ...
30/11/2020              20         20                20            20    20           20        20  ...              20                  20      19                   20                20               20                  20
31/03/2020               1          1                 1             1     1            1         1  ...               1                   1       1                    1                 1                1                   1
31/07/2020               5          5                 5             5     5            5         5  ...               5                   5       5                    5                 5                5                   5
31/08/2020               7          7                 7             7     7            7         7  ...               7                   7       7                    7                 7                7                   7
31/10/2020               1          1                 1             1     1            1         1  ...               1                   1       1                    1                 1                1                   1

[129 rows x 28 columns]
```

Comment: You are very close: right now your `result` is a dataframe with the date as the index, and all the columns are the number you want. `result['COD_IBGE'].plot(rot=90)` should do the trick

Comment: @jeremycg thanks for your tips. I guess I would have to sort by date, though, since it is out of order...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting your dates to datetime type, then `groupby` will sort your date automatically. Plus, you would get better looking x-ticks.

```
url = "https://ti.saude.rs.gov.br/covid19/download"
data = pd.read_csv('covid-rs.csv', delimiter=';', 
                   parse_dates=['DATA_CONFIRMACAO'],
                   dayfirst=True)

result = data[data['MUNICIPIO'] == 'SÃO LOURENÇO DO SUL'].groupby('DATA_CONFIRMACAO').count()
print(result)
```